# Extract a subgraph starting from one node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a large knowledge graph (below is a small part of it):
[image]

The P nodes are in a hierarchy and other nodes and relationships are connected to them, I want to retrieve the D nodes and the edges and nodes attached to them like C and X nodes shown in the sample image below.
I want to write a query where I provide the id for node P1 and subsequently retrieve all the connections and extract a subgraph. There are multiple other connections to the D nodes. I want to retrieve all of it and also filter the connections based on edge properties. How can I do this using a cypher query in Neo4j?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Neo4j 5, this should work.

```
MATCH path = (p:P {name:"P1"})-[ch:child*]->(p2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p2)<-[k:knows]-(d)
WHERE k.effectiveDate < date("2023-05-01") // put your  knows relationship filter here
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r:follows|has|likes]-(n) // include other relationship types as needed
WHERE r.strength > 0.5 // put your other relationship filter here
RETURN path
```

Your queries would be simpler if the relationships starting at P1 were all oriented in the same direction.

Comment: Could you please help me understand what you mean by p2 here? If it is the 1st level child of P1 then this query does not return anything as the D nodes are connected to P3.

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot the * to allow multiple child relationships. I have edited my answer.

Comment: This query isn't working. It probably only looks for the immediate child and not the subsequent descendents.

Comment: To get everything connected to P1 by outbound child relationships, run MATCH(p:P {name:"P1"})-[ch:child*]->(p2) RETURN p2